# How to build dynamic integration adapter?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, integration, acumatica

We have a scenario where we have multiple sources of data coming in from various external systems through API calls, SQL tables and physical files, and we now have to map it against a number of transaction templates. I want to build an integration adapter and UI where I can choose any entity data class and map it's fields to a class or action that will be used to create a transaction in our financial system.

I want to have an object type or class that can be modified dynamically, setup links between these objects and possibly create a set of rules that defines the interaction between these objects. I have seen some versions of this types of software that uses a drag and drop type of UI interface to do the mappings, so that will be the ideal end goal.

I'm coming from a C# .Net background, so I need some advise or tips on where to start and what to look at.

Comment: This is quite the challange and will require a ton of work to make it fully dynamical. I did something similar, although semi-dynamic. What I did is I use the source (API or .csv) to get a dynamic object, which has parameter names defined. Then by using a JSON configuration of the output model I dynamically map the source fields to the output class (model). So that might be a way if you don't want to do it by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently doing something similar. I wrote some code to turn data from our legacy system into JSON objects written out to flat files (1 file per data record in a table), and then wrote some code to cleanup that data and push it into Acumatica via the REST API.

I like flat file json objects because they can easily be hashed, and the hashes used to compare them to new data that comes in. Only data where the hash has changed needs to be merged or overwritten and then pushed into the target system. The file names are usually primary key values from whatever table you're working with. Our legacy system has a hierarchical (non-tabular/SQL-like data structure), so my mileage may be greater than doing with this with a well-normalized SQL database.

There are also products like Alteryx that are built for doing data pipelines the way you have proposed.

I would caution to be practical in the building of these types of things. For us, for example, we have a limited set of data that needs to come over, so we don't need the perfect abstraction for every data type. We inevitably had to do cleanup on legacy/3rd party data as well, and those problems aren't always so easy to abstract. I had previously built a system using closures for function passing in order to write custom cleanup routines for any abstract data problem I might encounter (sort of sounds like what you're talking about), but realized in the end that just writing simpler code that deals with specific data problems was cleaner and simpler to maintain....in the end, there is probably only a limited amount of data that needs to be synched.